# How to detect if request came from browser, not any broswer extension and etc

Tags: php, browser, cross-browser

I am creating a secure system which get request from other domains to create token and send back. To protect my system I want every request only came from browser not any browser extension like Postman etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if *http referer* is correct and verify the *user agent*. However both of those values can be set manually.

Another thing you can use is implementation of the *CSRF tokens* for your calls.